# Symfony2: how to set default value to id of from other entity?

Tags: php, symfony

What I'm trying to create is a form for a entity Movie in which admin can create a new Movie and choose if it's status is "accepted" (id 1 in table Status) or "not accepted" (id 2 in table Status).
But in the same time I want another form for regular users. Regular user doesn't have a choice with status, so it should be id 2 by default, without even showing the field. And this is my problem: I have no idea how to create it.

This is how Movie entity is joined with Status:

```
 /**
  * Statuses array
  *
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Stat", inversedBy="statuses")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  *
  */
protected $statuses;
```

And Status to Movie:

```
/**
 * Movies array
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Movie",
 *    mappedBy="statuses"
 * )
 */
protected $movies;
```

And part from Form for admin, which allows choosing status:

```
        $builder->add('status', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'AppBundle:Status',
            'multiple'      => false,
            'required'      => true,
            'empty_value'   =>'',
            'label'         => 'Status',
            'property'      => 'name',
            )
        );
```

Comment: When you create the new movie to pass into the form, create and set the default status object as well.